# Converting the string to xsd:date using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt, xsd, xslt-1.0, xsd-validation

Is there any way to convert the date which is a string(in the source)  into a xsd:date(in the target) .

SourceXML :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
          <root>
           <endDate>2016-07-08T02:05:58.058Z</endDate>
         </root>`

Expected targetXML :

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
 <return>
    <date>2016-07-08+05:58</date>
</return>`

In source it is string, where the target expect this as xsd:date. suggestions please.

Comment: This result `2016-07-08+05:58` makes no sense; the date is `2016-07-08` and the (optional) timezone is either `Z` or `+00:00`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

IMHO, you could use simply:

```
substring-before(endDate, 'T')
```

to extract the date portion of the given dateTime.